# Detecting High Surrogates in a String using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, android, regex, unicode, utf-8

I want to check whether a String contains any High Surrogates. In Java I would use Character.isHighSurrogate(c) and this works.

In regex (using the implementation provided by Android 2.3.3 SDK), I was expecting this to work:

`[\uD800-\uDBFF]`

but it doesn't.

I am using the char:  (codepoint: 177700) to test this (works in my java check but not the regex check).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex engine looks at *code **points**,* not at *code **units**.* It has no choice, because this is a fundamental requirement of [UTS#18 Level 1 Unicode support](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support):

> Level 1: Basic Unicode Support. At this level, the regular expression engine provides support for Unicode characters as basic logical units. (This is independent of the actual serialization of Unicode as UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, or UTF-32LE.) This is a minimal level for useful Unicode support. It does not account for end-user expectations for character support, but does satisfy most low-level programmer requirements. The results of regular expression matching at this level are independent of country or language. At this level, the user of the regular expression engine would need to write more complicated regular expressions to do full Unicode processing.

And so this is true whether in the normal JDK regex engine, or in the Android regex engine that JNIs into the [ICU regex library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) for much better Unicode support than the JDK provides. Amongst other things, ICU meets all Level-1 requirements and also some Level-2 requirements such as full properties (the upcoming 2.7), graphemes, and fancier boundaries.  You don’t get to Level 1 before JDK7, and even there it lacks the rest of them. It is very hard to work with Unicode without grapheme support, and impossible without code-point support.

Sometimes you can get these things to find isolated surrogates, or reversed ones, but these are not supposed to occur in data valid for interchange.

In general, you want to stay as far away from any code-unit interface to anything as you possibly can, and use only those APIs that support a code-point interface instead.  Code-units are a curse.

Also, stay very far away from the Java preprocessor.  You’ll get no joy from your regexes that way.  The ICU regex engine supports both `\x{ᴄᴏᴅᴇ ᴘᴏɪɴᴛ}` and `\N{ᴄʜᴀʀɴᴀᴍᴇ}`, so you should use those.

Why are you monkeying around with wicked-nasty code **units**, anyway? They violate the code-point abstraction.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. The only reason I was using the code units (i.e. [\uD800-\uDBFF]) was because I couldn't see any way to match against codepoints specifically (in the Pattern documentation of the Android SDK). Out of interest, I suppose it could never match against \p{inHighSurrogates} because a High Surrogate is "always" half of a codepoint? Well, I suppose it would match in situations where there is a High Surrogate not followed by a Low Surrogate...?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), there is an example for matching Greek characters linking to [Character.UnicodeBlock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html)

> **Classes for Unicode blocks and categories**
>
> \p{InGreek}    A character in the Greek block (simple [block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html))

The available constants in that class contain [LOW_SURROGATES](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#LOW_SURROGATES), assuming the regex impl on android is compatible to the jdk one, I tried the following code:

```
String test = new String(Character.toChars(177700));

System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\p{InLowSurrogates}").matcher(test).find());
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\p{InLOW_SURROGATES}").matcher(test).find());
```

Which prints "true" two times, meaning both naming styles work and it correctly detects low surrogates.

Strangely, the same code does not work for high surrogates, i.e. the following lines both print false:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\p{InHighSurrogates}").matcher(test).find());
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\p{InHIGH_SURROGATES}").matcher(test).find());
```